# Unmounting a React component the correct way

Tags: reactjs

```
export class Child extends React.Component{
  unmount() {
    const node = ReactDOM.getDOMNode(this);
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(node );
}

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.unmount.bind(this)}>Unmount</button>
  }
}
```

For the above sample component, would it possible to unmount it on click using `unmountComponentAtNode`?

Comment: Would you be open to just hiding the component such that React will unmount it for you? If a component is no longer in use, React will unmount it. Unless you’ve got a very rare use-case, I would think that’s your best bet.

Comment: even if there was a way to do exactly this... having a component unmount itself is highly antithetical to the purpose of react. why wouldn't the parent that actually renders this component be responsible for when its children are mounted or not

Comment: @twils0 thanks. i just put ternary operator in the parent component that toggles true/false and renders/unmounts the child accordingly. that fixed it :)

Answer (score 4):

React application is always a components composition, or in different words - components tree. It means that every component has parent component, which renders it, it is only falsy statement for root component, mostly we name it **App**, but we do not talk about it in that question. Above all, we can say that a component, which needs to be unmounted, always has a parent component.

As we did the assumption in first paragraph, the correct way of unmounting React component is to remove it from render method in parent component. It can be done in many ways, the simplest is just an conditional component rendering like:

```
class IAmParentComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<div>{this.state.show && <YourChildComponentToUnmount/>}</div>)
  }
}
```

Above example shows **IAmParentComponent** as container component which holds a state, and the **YourChildComponentToUnmount** will render if `this.state.show` is `true`, will unomount after state change from `true` to `false`.

Back to your code with callback, the callback should be send into component by props, and the parent component should do the state change related to removing the component from render tree, what exactly will start unmount phase of the component, and finally component will be removed from UI.

In conclusion, component unmount should be in responsibility of component above it, component should not unmount itself.

Comment: This helped me to show/hide modals. I wasn't getting updated modal states that came from parent states (as props to modal). I used your method and now they are synced up

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way react.
The best way to unmount an element is to tell the parent to remove the child from the rendered children of the parent.

Look at this example.
Here we have the CardContainer class and CardItem class.The CardItem item class has a delete self button. This method send an event to the parent container to remove itself from the rendered children.

```
    const carddata = [
      {key:1 ,name: 'Card A',visible:true},
      {key:2 ,name: 'Card B',visible:true}
    ];

    class CardItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.handleClick=this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    componentWillUnmount(){
        console.log('unmount')
    }
    handleClick(){
        this.props.destroy(this.props.id)
    }
    render(){
        return(<div>
                Card 
                <button onClick={this.handleClick} >delete</button>
                </div>)
    }

  }

  class CardContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {data: carddata};
        this.destroy = this.destroy.bind(this);
    }
    destroy(elementKey){
        console.log(elementKey)
        debugger
        let result = this.state.data.filter(item=> item.key !==elementKey);
        this.setState({data: result});

    }

    render(){

          return (<div>
                  Card Container
                  {this.state.data.map((card,index) => {
                    return <CardItem key={card.key} id={card.key} name={card.name} destroy={this.destroy}/>
                    })
                  }
                 </div>)
    }

  }
```